# Can I get my citizenship without physical green card

Tags: immigration, citizenship

Am wondering if i can get a US citizenship without a green card(hard copy), I had one but it got stolen. (have a police report for it)

I can apply for a replacement but since my interview will be in few days, I think it might be a waste of money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still become a citizen. Here is a site that shows you how to apply for a replacement.
https://www.uscis.gov/green-card/after-green-card-granted/replace-a-green-card

You are supposed to apply for one even if the interview is coming soon.

Comment: sorry I edited my question.

Comment: You are supposed to apply for a new one even if the hearing is coming up.